# MySQL - How can I enter custom value and override trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, overriding

I have a MySQL trigger ending with a case statement regarding the entry of another column.

```
NEW.reference_column = CASE NEW.entry_column
WHEN "Test Value 1" THEN 1
WHEN "Test Value 2 " THEN 2
WHEN "Test Value 3" THEN 3
ELSE 4 END;
```

However, sometimes there is values in the reference_column that can't be predicted and I don't want the else value to be inserted but a custom one. How can I enter a custom value in the entry_column and override the trigger so it doesn't insert the else value?

Edit: I tried to skip the ELSE value but then it just gives me a blank correction when trying to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm . . . Would logic like this do what you want?

```
NEW.reference_column = (CASE WHEN NEW.entry_column = 'Test Value 1' THEN 1
                             WHEN NEW.entry_column = 'Test Value 2' THEN 2
                             WHEN NEW.entry_column = 'Test Value 3' THEN 3
                             WHEN NEW.entry_column LIKE 'Custom %'
                             THEN substring_index(NEW.entry_column, ' ', -1) + 0
                             ELSE 4
                        END);
```

New values would be inserted as `'Custom 5'`.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer opened my mind for how I could design the solution.